# What's the difference between use a class selector and a class with an element?

Tags: html, css

I have seen this as the norm:

[image]

It has a class selector with a property and a value, then that class is called below.

That makes sense.

But i have seen this too:

[image]

There is an element with a class in the `<style>` section, what's the difference  and why is there a need to put the element with the class as the selector instead of just the class?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/CSS_basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.co` will select *all elements* with that class. `div.co` will only select `div` elements with that class. It's more [specific](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp).